# How can I delete using ajax in laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

**BLADE FILE**

```
<td><button class="deleteuser" data-id="{{ $user->id }}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" >DELETE</button>
                                            </td>
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
        $(".deleteuser").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var token = $(this).data("token");
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "user/delete/"+id,
            type: 'DELETE',
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {
                "id": id,
                "_method": 'DELETE',
                "_token": token,
            },
            success: function ()
            {
                console.log("it Work");
            }
        });

        console.log("It failed");
    });
});
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function destroyuser($id){  
        $this->authorize('Admin'); 
        User::find($id)->delete($id);
        return response()->json([
        'success' => 'Record has been deleted successfully!'
        ]);
        return view('viewuser');
    }
```

If I click on delete button, there is no response. Any suggestion or correction will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: The response happening in console, if you want to log the response message you have sent just change the success function to be: ```success: function (res){console.log("it Work: ", res);}```

Comment: What does "no response" mean? What do your browser console and network activity say? Why are you doing no error checking in your controller code?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your url as this and check:

```
var id = data.id;

var url = "{{route('your_route',":id") }}";

url = url.replace(':id', id);
```

pass **url** in your ajax url param

***Or make above changes:***

**BLADE FILE**

```
<td>
<button style="background-color: red;" onclick="clickOffConfirmed" title="Delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md delete"><i class="la la-trash" style="color: white;"></i></button>
</td>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function ()
    {
      var obj = $(this);
      var id=$(this).closest('td').find(".delete_id").val();
      var result = confirm("Are you sure want to delete?");
      if(result)
      {
        $.ajax(
        {
          type: "POST",
          url: "{{route('delete_method')}}",
          data: {
            '_token': $('input[name="_token"]').val(),
            'id': id
          },
          cache: false,
          success: function (data)
          {
            if (data.status === 'success')
            {
              window.location = "{{route('redirect_route')}}";
              toastr["success"]("Deleted Successfully", "Success");
            } 
            else if (data.status === 'error')
            {
              location.reload();
              toastr["error"]("Something went wrong", "Opps");
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function delete_method(Request $request)
    {
        $del = ModelName::findOrFail($request->id)->delete();

        if($del)
        {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'success']);
        }
        else{
            return response()->json(['status' => 'error']);
        } 
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('/test/delete','TestController@delete_method')->name('delete_method');
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't know if the JS is in a different file but to check if the "$( document ).ready()" is working add a console.log() call at the beginning.

   ```
   $(document).ready( function () {console.log("document is ready")
   $(".deleteuser").click(function(){
   ```

Refresh the page and check if "document is ready" is logged to the console.
If it isn't then the javascript is not loading

2. Check if the route is properly defined

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax codes, change this:

```
url: "user/delete/"+id,
```

To:

```
url: "{{ url('user/delete') }}/" + id
```

If your ajax codes are inside of your blade file also you can use this way:

```
url: "{{ route('YOUR_ROUTE_NAME', $user->id) }}/"
```

Answer (score -1):

You incorrectly define delete function!
change

```
 User::find($id)->delete($id);
```

To

```
 User::find($id)->delete();
```

Comment: Correction done in delete function. But still not working

Comment: what is your response code in ajax call?